# throttle executes the function at most one time per wait period right?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to throttle my function every 100 milliseconds.  In the following code, I expect only 1 and 3 to be printed.  But 2 is also printed in the actual result.

```js
function say(what) {
  console.log(what);
}

const t = _.throttle(say, 100);

setTimeout(() => {
  t(1);
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
  t(1);
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
  t(1);
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
  t(1);
}, 55);
setTimeout(() => {
  t(2);
}, 55);
setTimeout(() => {
  t(3);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

I have to change the throttle wait time to 500 in order to filter out the 2.

Maybe my understanding of throttle is wrong.  Shouldn't throttle execute the function at most one time per wait period?

Comment: The call to `t(2)` is the last call made during the first 100ms.  It'll be called when the 100ms expires. If you add the current timestamp (`Date.now()`) to the log messages you'll see that the call to `t(2)` happens almost exactly 100ms after the first `t(1)` call.

Comment: The feels a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Mind sharing the exact issue instead of this vague representation?

Comment: @Pointy so the first function is called always, and only the subsequent functions are spread out by wait time.  Is that right?

Comment: @techguy2000 unless you set `trailing` to `false` - `_.throttle(say, 100, { trailing: false });` This would log `1` and then `3`

Comment: alternatively, you could set `leading` to `false` and it would log `2` and then `3` and not log `1` at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of how you are using this throttle setup is not quite right.

To directly answer:

> Shouldn't throttle execute the function at most one time per wait period?

With no options passed in, throttle will execute at the beginning and the end of the wait period (twice), provided the throttled function was called more than once in that period.

At 50ms your first function is called, and 'throttle' runs it immediately, also at this time your next f(1) is queued up to be called at 100ms. But then another f(1) is called, and another f(1) and then an f(2), and each new one replaces the last as the function to be called at 100ms (which is the time you've passed into throttle). Then over 100ms passes and then f(3) is called more or less when it should be.

If you don't pass any options into `_.throttle` it will immediately call the first function run (at 0ms) and then will call the last function run inside the set time period once that time elapses.

Using @zfrisch's code as a start:

```
function say(what) {
  console.log(what);
}

const t = _.throttle(say, 100);
const TO = (n, i) => setTimeout(() => {
  t(n);
}, i);

TO(1, 50); // logged immediately
TO(1, 50);
TO(1, 50);
TO(1, 55);
TO(2, 55); // logged at 100ms (as it was the last function attempted)
```

```
function say(what) {
  console.log(what);
}

const t = _.throttle(say, 100, { leading: false });
const TO = (n, i) => setTimeout(() => {
  t(n);
}, i);

TO(1, 50); // not logged at all
TO(1, 50);
TO(1, 50);
TO(1, 55);
TO(2, 55); // logged at 100ms (as it was the last function attempted)
```

```
function say(what) {
  console.log(what);
}

const t = _.throttle(say, 100, { trailing: false });
const TO = (n, i) => setTimeout(() => {
  t(n);
}, i);

TO(1, 50); // logged immediately
TO(1, 50);
TO(1, 50);
TO(1, 55);
TO(2, 55); // not logged at all
```

Comment: Didn't expect this to be so active.  This really helps me understand what throttle is doing. Thanks!

Comment: Nice Answer! I didn't see your edit and put some polish on mine, but I like this! +1

Answer (score 3):

Throttle will delay the execution by the wait time, but the function will still be called. In your example, it will happen like follows: 50ms after the script start the first 1 is logged, and at this moment throttle will start counting 100ms. Any call to t in this period will be delayed. After the 100ms passed, the last call made to t will be triggered. 100ms passes again and t is not called, so nothing happens, then the last call happens.

Comment: From the documentation: **Creates a throttled function that only invokes func at most once per every wait milliseconds** - the function is not still called

Comment: @DerekPollard the wording of the answer could be better, but I think the point being made here is that there was no other call after `t(2)` to override it when the timeout window had passed, so then at that point `t(2)` invokes the underlying call `say(2)`.

Comment: @DerekPollard But per the lodash source code, `leading` and `trailing` are set to `true` https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/throttle.js. So the function is called immediately, 100ms later the most recent called function (in this case t(2)) is called, and then a little under 400ms later the final function is called

Comment: How does this contradict what I said? The function is still called not more the once per wait time. The call is delayed, but it happens at the end of the wait time. If you make 1000 calls spread over 1 second with wait time 100ms you will get the function invoked at most 10 times (11 if leading and trailing are true).

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala my question is how does _that_ contradict what this answer is saying?

Comment: @DerekPollard as I noted in another comment, if you modify the fiddle to include the timestamp in the `console.log()` message, you'll see that the contract of `_.throttle()` is fulfilled — the `t(2)` call is delayed until 100ms has elapsed. Basically the throttled wrapper function holds on to the most recent call and invokes it once the timer has expired (unless `trailing` is `false`).

Comment: @Pointy - that explanation makes more sense than a blanket statement, like this does: *Throttle will delay the execution by the wait time, but the function will still be called* - for that reason alone, IMHO, this answer is incorrect

Comment: @DerekPollard *After the 100ms passed, the last call made to t will be triggered.* — that is in fact exactly what happens.

Comment: Right, so at best, this answer is contradictory

Comment: @DerekPollard I don't see which bit is contradictory?

Comment: @BrettEast **Throttle will delay the execution by the wait time, but the function will still be called.** ...  **After the 100ms passed, the last call made to t will be triggered**

Comment: @DerekPollard those sentences are basically the same. "Throttle will delay the execution of the function by the wait time" - "After the wait time, throttle will execute the function"

Comment: @DerekPollard But hopefully my answer is a little more clear :)

Comment: *"Throttle will delay the execution by the wait time, **but the function will still be called**"* to me, at least, it sounds like every function call will still be executed, AFTER the execution delay. I upvoted your answer because it makes more logical sense and doesn't contradict

Comment: It is not a contradiction. The function will be called, that is a fact. It is just not be called as many times as the wrapper was called.

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem:

It's easy to see how you assumed your code would work. It's not a hard thing to misinterpret, but the reason why it doesn't execute the way you're expecting is because of the default behavior of the function.

### The `Throttle` Function:

[image: Throttle Parameters]

From the above you can see that `Throttle` takes a `function` and a `wait` time in milliseconds as its first two parameters, but the `options` are not used in your current code and those are the key to solving your issue.

---

### The Options:

`_.throttle` has the options `leading` and `trailing`. These two are both defaulted to `true`.

Unfortunately the named options, though apt, are not crystal clear in purpose simply from their names unless you're familiar with the process that's happening behind the curtain.

---

### An Explanation:

**`leading`** refers to those that are called at the applicable times. These would be:

- the initial call
- the next call *after* 100ms
- the next call *after* another 100ms
- etc.

**`trailing`** refers to the last call of the `throttle` function made *during* the interval. This function is not simply discarded, but postponed until it *can* be called. Think of it as a slot that's available to be filled during the interval. When a call is made during the interval, that slot is filled/replaced with the new function.

This can be illustrated:

- Initial Call is Made
- A call with `function 1` is made during interval
- A call with `function 2` is made during the interval
- `function 2` replaces `function 1` as the trailing function
- At `100ms` `function 2` is run.

An important concept, and ultimately the crux of what's happening in your code, is the following:

If both options are `true`, the **trailing** function made **during** the interval will be called **before** a new **leading** call to the `throttle` function.

Because of this the new **leading** call becomes a **trailing** call for the end of the next interval.

The documentation that I've pulled direct from the lodash official site does specify this, but you would be forgiven for misunderstanding as it's a lot to comprehend if you're not familiar with their terms:

---

[image: Throttle Documentation]
[*See the Throttle Documentation on Lodash](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle)

---

### What does this mean?

In your example, when you call `_.throttle` it will, **by default**, wait to perform the function call until the interval has passed and continuously rewrite the function waiting to be called during the `100ms` interval. To change this and only accept/perform the calls that are made after the interval, you can turn `trailing` to `false`.

### A Working Solution:

```js
function say(what) {
console.group();
  console.log(what);
  console.timeLog("check");
  console.groupEnd();
}

const t = _.throttle(say, 100, {trailing: false});
const TO = (n, i) => setTimeout(()=>{t(n);}, i);
 
console.time("check");
TO(1,50);
TO(1,50);
TO(1,50);
TO(1,55);
TO(2,55);
TO(3,500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So you know, the stackoverflow snippet shows the time a console event occurred on the right of the "console" display

Comment: This is a nice thought, as `setTimeout` can be a little unpredictable. But it's not the case here. Throttle means that the last function 'attempted' to be called within the set time period will be called when that time elapses. Which is why the difference in time there is nearly exactly 100ms. To test this set the throttle time to 200ms, and you'll see that's the new difference in time.

Comment: @BrettEast oh? Let me check that out. :) Thanks for the comment. I'll remove my answer if it's not the case.

Comment: @zfrisch no problem, it just so happens that lodash throttle defaults to `leading` and `trailing` calls

Comment: @BrettEast I decided to rewrite my answer. Please let me know if you have anything to point out with the edit :)